Why is stellar sdk throwing [Object object] not a memo when memo is added when building transaction?
Please help me out, i'm stuck. I'm trying to add a memo when generating a wallet on the stellar network but the SDK keeps throwing this XDR write error.
Error stack trace:
 TypeError: XDR Write Error: [object Object] is not a Memo at Function.write (webpack://WalletSDK/node_modules/@stellar/js-xdr/src/union.js:85:1) at Function.write (webpack://WalletSDK/node_modules/@stellar/js-xdr/src/struct.js:31:1) at Function.write (webpack://WalletSDK/node_modules/@stellar/js-xdr/src/union.js:88:1) at Function.write (webpack://WalletSDK/node_modules/@stellar/js-xdr/src/struct.js:31:1) at Function.toXDR (webpack://WalletSDK/node_modules/@stellar/js-xdr/src/xdr-type.js:57:1) at ChildStruct.toXDR (webpack://WalletSDK/node_modules/@stellar/js-xdr/src/xdr-type.js:12:1) at Transaction.signatureBase (webpack://WalletSDK/node_modules/@stellar/stellar-base/lib/transaction.js:293:1) at Transaction.hash (webpack://WalletSDK/node_modules/@stellar/stellar-base/lib/transaction_base.js:224:1) at Transaction.sign (webpack://WalletSDK/node_modules/@stellar/stellar-base/lib/transaction_base.js:88:1) at SigningKeypair.__webpack_modules__../src/walletSdk/Horizon/Account.ts.exports.SigningKeypair.SigningKeypair.sign (webpack://WalletSDK/src/walletSdk/Horizon/Account.ts:64:1)|
Code:
const createTxn = txBuilder
      .createAccount(createdAccountKeyPair)
      .setMemo(new Memo(MemoText, 'test-memo'))
      .build();

    const signed = sponsorSigningKeyPair.sign(createTxn);

These are the imports
import { Memo, xdr, MemoText } from '@stellar/stellar-sdk';
import {
  StellarConfiguration,
  Wallet,
  Keypair,
  AccountKeypair,
  IssuedAssetId,
  PublicKeypair,
  SigningKeypair,
  NativeAssetId,
} from '@stellar/typescript-wallet-sdk';

Versions:
"@stellar/stellar-sdk": "^12.1.0",
"@stellar/typescript-wallet-sdk": "^1.7.0",

this is my input
const createTxn = txBuilder
      .createAccount(createdAccountKeyPair)
      .setMemo(new Memo(MemoText, 'test-memo'))
      .build();

    const signed = sponsorSigningKeyPair.sign(createTxn);

